# Let $r_t+ru_x+ur_x=0$ and $u_t+uu_x=0$ for $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $r(x,0)=g(x)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let $r_t+ru_x+ur_x=0$ and $u_t+uu_x=0$ for $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $r(x,0)=g(x)$.

I know I have to solve for implicit $u$ first and then $r$, but I don't know if I'm using the right method here.

What I've got so far is:

$\frac{dx}{ds}=u$, $\frac{dt}{ds}=1$, & $\frac{du}{ds}=0$ while initial conditions are $x=\tau$, $t=0$, and $u(x,0)=f(x)$.

Solving these odes I get, $t=s$, $u=f(x)$, but that I don't know how to find $x$, since $\frac{dx}{ds}=u$.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.